# Weird notation in Bartok's Microcosmos, Book 1, No. 9

Tags: notation, bartok, mikrokosmos

In Bartok's Microcosmos Book 1, Number 9, I found these notes floating between the staves, without any lines.

[image]

What do they mean? What notes are supposed to be played?

Comment: I remember seeing similar notation in Boosey & Hawkes condensed scores corresponding to unpitched percussion parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a footnote at the bottom of that image but it's in Russian.

The english translation in my version of this book (which lists this piece as *9. Syncopation 1*) says:

> 9. The rhythmic feeling of the suspensions should be emphazised by some
>    energetic movement such as tapping with the foot in the places marked
>    by rhythmic signatures between the staves.

So, just tap your foot for these beats.

Comment: In fact the Russian footnote in OP’s excerpt is much less informative: it just says “The asterisk by this piece’s number indicates that it has an author’s note at the end of the volume *(editor’s note)*.”

Comment: @PLL * footnote: there is a footnote later in the book, about a note you play with your foot.

Comment: If these are unpitched notes, wouldn't it would be more intuitive to use x-head notes instead?